# How can I modify the color grading (midtone) of the image captured using the RPI camera module?

Tags: camera, picamera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Is it possible to configure the color grading (adjust the midtone) of the image captured using Raspberry Pi camera module version 1.3 and the Picamera2 library?

Comment: What have you learned from reading the documentation for the picamera2 library?

Comment: Hello joan! Based on the picamera2 we can change the white balance of the image taken, However, what we need to apply is change midtone color grading.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.